# How to pass data and segue to a view controller embedded in a navigation controller in a different tab in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

When the user presses a button  `ViewController1`, I would like to segue to `ViewController2` and pass data to it. In all the methods I've tried either the `NavigationController` disappears or the `TabBar` disappears, which I don't want. Is there a better way to bring the user from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`?.

[image]

Comment: you can go to the particular tab on click button after that you need to do segue to go to the `ViewController2`

Comment: @wings so I'd have to programatically change tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 and then add code to the viewDidAppear() of the rootViewController to segue to View Controller 2?

Comment: yes you can try this

Comment: @wings but how do I pass data from ViewContoller1 to ViewController2 in this method?

Comment: you need to take your data to `VC1` -> `tabBar` -> `VC2` but I am not sure it is right or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a **NavigationViewController** in between **TabBarController** and **ViewController1**. Then perform segue from **viewController1** to **viewController2** and pass the data using `prepare` function